# windows not booting from grub menu

Tags: grub2

I have an SSD with 2 partitions. The first partition belongs to Windows 10 and it worked fine. I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on the second partition and it also works fine.

When I boot, grub is correctly displayed and shows both Windows and Ubuntu. If I select Ubuntu it can boot without issue and I can even access the Windows partition from Ubuntu, but if I try to boot Windows 10 it displays a black screen (like it will start normally) for a few seconds (perhaps 10 or 11 seconds) and then it goes back to grub without showing any message.

windows entry in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

`menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/nvme0n1p1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-54F2-CFDE'`  {

```
insmod part_gpt

insmod fat

search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 54F2-CFDE

chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```

}`

Comment: As always, boot Windows directly (UEFI settings > Boot). If it boots correctly make sure to 1. disable Windows' Fast Startup feature, a must when dual-booting; 2. let it install all pending updates and reboot as many times it needs, if applicable; 3. change the boot order back to Ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: If it doesn't boot directly then it won't from Grub either obviously.

Comment: if I change boot order from ubuntu to windows then while rebooting it gives preparing automatic repair screen.

Comment: There's your answer. You may need to boot Windows installation media and repair it. Not an Ubuntu question.

Comment: ok thanks @ChanganAuto